# Storing images from android-volley in internal storage

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, internal-storage

Please forgive me if the question is answered elsewhere (although I did try to search both SO and google).

I am designing an app in which one activity will display some icons in a gridview. For the most part the icons will not change, however they might. I would prefer not to have to update the entire app if they do change. Therefore I would like to check my server first to see if there are any changes to the icon set. If they have changed I'd like to save the image locally (not in cache) for current and future use.

My question is, is volley configurable so that I can use internal storage instead of cache so that the images are available long-term.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: For the things you want to achieve I would use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks!